# Changing theme at runtime, need View to redraw but it does not

Tags: android, refresh, ondraw, invalidation, android-theme

I have searched but cant find a solution to my problem.
What I need to do is set a random theme and then have all other views adopt this theme. The randomising of the theme isn't the problem, I know it's woking. Whats the issue is refreshing the views already in the stack.

I call

```
int theme = Constants.THEMES[randomInt];
setTheme(theme);
```

in an activity somewhere in the stack and then call `invalidate()` on that activity. Nothing happens in that activity but when I go to other activities the new theme applies.

Also when I go 'back' to my `mainActivity` I can't figure out how to get the `View` to redraw.

I'm calling

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(refreshNeeded){
        getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(
        android.R.id.content).getRootView().invalidate();
    }
}
```

but nothing again. I cant figure out how to get it to redraw with the new theme.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score -1):

Call this at `Button click`

```
    getApplication().setTheme(R.style.Theme_Black);
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Black);
    Intent n = new Intent(activityA.this , activityB.class);
    startactivity(n);
```

It will work. But you must have all widget styles in your `themes.xml` in `values` folder

Comment: I mentioned that the new theme is being applied to new activities. The problem I'm having is applying it to the current view and other views in the stack (as in when the user presses the back button). `getApplication().setTheme(theme);` doesn't change anything does it?

Comment: At the moment my only option seems to be:
`if(refreshNeeded){`
`i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`
`Intent i = getIntent();`
`startActivity(i);`
`}`
not the best solution.